# How does the Ctrl + Z keyboard shortcut actually work in general?

Tags: keyboard, logic, shortcut

I mean, its not about some code or something, but how does that shortcut work in general, like when I am working on a something and accidentally, I delete a chunk of text, how does the shortcut, revert it back on to the screen, don't give me the code or something, but take instances of elements in the coding world like whiles, ifs etc. How did the creator get the idea that something like this should even exist?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways this can be achieved, the decision how, is up to the developer to decide.

One way is to make use of a stack, where the where the state of this program is stored in such a structure.

Another way is use a design pattern called the command pattern which is often used to implement undo redo functionality, this is very similar to a stack, but instead of storing the program state, you save the action done to the program together with a similar action to undo the executed one.